# jQuery offset fixed header using scrollTop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to a create a vertically smooth scrolling website, using jQuery. I am using this JavaScript and this tutorial [Smooth Scrolling Website](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/06/02/smooth-vertical-or-horizontal-page-scrolling-with-jquery/) to create the site.

But I'm having trouble with a fixed header, the scrolling works fine but it appears half way down the relevant `div` because the `div` is aligning to the top of the page, not just below the fixed header as I would like it too.

I've tried adding an offset to scrollTop but all hell breaks loose on the page, things appearing above the fixed header etc. Just a page mash-up really. If anybody could shed any light it would be greatly appreciated.

```
$(function() {  
        $('ul.menu a').bind('click',function(event){
                    var $anchor = $(this);

                    $('html, body').stop().animate({
                        scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
                    }, 1500,'easeInOutExpo');
                    /*
                    if you don't want to use the easing effects:
                    $('html, body').stop().animate({
                        scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
                    }, 1000);
                    */
                    event.preventDefault();
                });
            });
```

I've found this code on StackOverflow (`+ $('.fixedheader').outerHeight()`) and added it to my code (after `scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top`) it does work but seems to have the opposite effect. Anybody know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this,

```
+ $('.fixedheader').outerHeight()
```

Should be

```
- $('.fixedheader').outerHeight()
```

So silly of me, cheers anyway guys.